# What does /?s=free&cat=plus-5-results mean in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google Analytics, I am seeing some **"/?s=free&cat=plus-5-results"** under **What pages do your users visit?**

Does anyone know how I need to deal with this?

Comment: It means that some users, or bots, are trying to visit that URL on the site. What is there to 'deal with'?

Answer (score 1):

So it means that there were some requests for given url processed by your site.

Probably some user have requested it.

This request is a search for phrase “free” in category “plus 5 results”

Comment: I wonder if I remember correctly that `cat` only accepts category Id (integer)?

Comment: @birgire Yup - you remember that correctly. By default it expects ID, which is integer, but... I've seen many strange ways of implementation of search/filters in some premium themes, so... It can be such case. Nevertheless - it's not a default WP behavior.